# Find $P(X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3)$ and $P(X_1\gt X_2|X_2\lt X_3)$ for $X_1, X_2, X_3$ i.i.d random variable.

Tags: probability

Find $P(X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3)$ and $P(X_1\gt X_2|X_2\lt X_3)$ for $X_1, X_2, X_3$ i.i.d random variable.

For $P(X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3)$, since there exists six possible orders, $P(X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3)={1\over 6}$. Is this true for any distribution? Can I get $P(X_1\lt X_2\lt X_3\lt...\lt X_n)={1\over n!}$?

For $P(X_1\gt X_2|X_2\lt X_3)$, since $X_1\gt X_2$ and $X_2\lt X_3$ are independent event (am I right?), I just simply get $P(X_1\gt X_2|X_2\lt X_3)={1\over2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, this is true for any i.i.d  random variables as long as the probabilities of any two being equal is 0. So if they are continuous random variables it is true, if they are discrete then no.

For the second part, you need to consider your $6$ equally likely orderings
$X_1 < X_2 < X_3$, $X_2 < X_1 < X_3$, $X_1 < X_3 < X_2$, $X_3 < X_1 < X_2$, $X_2 < X_3 < X_1$, and $X_3 < X_2 < X_1$. If $X_2 < X_3$ then there are only $3$ of these orderings possible, $X_1 < X_2 < X_3$, $X_2 < X_1 < X_3$, and $X_2 < X_3 < X_1$. Of these $X_1 > X_2$ in $2$ of them, so the probability is actually $\frac23$.

Intuitively this is because $X_2 < X_3$ and $X_1 > X_2$ are not independent. If you think about it, $X_2 < X_3$ means that $X_2$ is more likely to be small, and so it is more likely that $X_1$ is greater than it.

Comment: would it be $2\over 3$ instead of $1\over 3$?

Comment: @YibeiHe Good catch! Just fixed it.